# How can I solve this Interface Segregation Principle Violation

Tags: c#, oop, interface-segregation-principle

I'm facing a similar scenario to this issue and I was wondering if it's possible to get around a cleaner solution.

Supposing we have a party that has People on it, We have the interface:

```
public interface IPerson {
 void Arrive();
 void Dance();
}
```

And its implementations, people that are able to dance

```
public class PersonThatCanDance : IPerson {

 public void Arrive() {

  //Logic related to arriving
 }

 public void Dance() {

  //Logic related to dancing
 }
}
```

and those who aren't

```
 public class PersonThatCannotDance : IPerson {

  public void Arrive() {

   //Logic related to arriving
  }

  public void Dance() {
  
  }
}
```

Knowing this, now we have the party with 2 people

```
public class Party {

 private IPerson person1;
 private IPerson person2
 
 private void StartParty() {

  person1.Arrive();
  person2.Arrive();
 }

 private void StartMusic() {
 
  person1.Dance();
  person2.Dance();
 }
}
```

With this scenario settled, the problem comes when we want to make the party not care if the person is a person that can dance or not. The party throws the people into dancing no matter if they have functionality to do so.

From what I understand, the existence of the Dance() method in PersonThatCannotDance is a violation of ISP but making the party not care about what kind of person is preventing me from respecting the principle.

Is there a way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: rename `Dance` to `RespondToMusic` and voilà

Comment: PersonThatCannotDance would still have a non-implemented method and still violate ISP, doesn't it?

Comment: I would argue that is a matter of semantics. I can say that PersonThatCannotDance has a no-op response to music. Of course the idea is as contrived as the question. If the party doesn't care if the person can dance it should not explicitly try to make the person dance.

Comment: `Dance` method should belong to an interface like `ICanDance` a person can dance should implement `ICanDance` interface. And at your party class you should check it like `if(person is ICanDance var dancer) dancer.Dance()`

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. it is violation of ISP.

```
public interface IArrive : IPerson {
 void Arrive();
 DateTime Time {get;set;}
 string Mode {get;set;}
}

public interface IDance: IPerson {
 void Dance();
 DateTime duration {get;set;}
 string Type {get;set;}
}

public interface IPerson   {
 string Name {get;set;}
 void Dress();
}
```

Now Implementations looks like this, people that are able to dance

```
public class PersonThatCanDance : IArrive,IDance {

 string Name {get; set;}

public void Dress() {

  //Logic related to arriving
 }

 public void Arrive() {

  //Logic related to arriving
 }

 public void Dance() {

  //Logic related to dancing
 }
}
```

and those who aren't

```
 public class PersonThatCannotDance : IArrive {

string Name {get; set;}

public void Dress() {

  //Logic related to arriving
 }

  public void Arrive() {

   //Logic related to arriving
  }
}
```

In Party Class

```
public class Party {

 private IPerson person1 = new PersonThatCanDance();
 private IPerson person2 = new PersonThatCannotDance(); 
 
 private void StartParty() {

  ((IArrive)person1).Arrive();
  ((IArrive)person2).Arrive();
  
 }

 private void StartMusic() {
 
  if(person1 is IDance)
  {
    ((IDance)person1).Dance();
  }

  if(person2 is IDance)
  {
    ((IDance)person2).Dance();
  }
 }
}
```

Now I hope this solution will work. please let me know if still have doubt.

Comment: This would solve the ISP but the real problem is resolving it at the same time as handling the party only knowing that the people are IPerson, agnostic of if they are the type that can or cannot dance

Comment: i forgot to describe party class. pass list of iperson in parameter of method and look like

void dance(list<IPerson> persons)
{
    foreach(person in persons)
    {
       if (person is IDance)
        person.dance();
    }
}

Comment: now it is full code. please let me know that it has resolved your doubt or problem. in real scenario, it should list of person and check one by one that that person is dance kind of person or not . if yes then call dance method or behavior of that person.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to determine the right design for your situation, but I can offer a design that's broadly applicable:

```
public interface IPerson {
    void Arrive();
}

public class PersonThatCanDance : IPerson {
    public void Arrive(Party party) {
        //Logic related to arriving
        ...
        party.AddDancers(this);
    }

    public void Dance() {
        //Logic related to dancing
        ...
    }
}

public class PersonThatCannotDance : IPerson {
    public void Arrive(Party party) {
        //Logic related to arriving
        ...
    }
}

public class Party {
    private IPerson person1;
    private IPerson person2;

    ArrayList dancers = new ArrayList();

    private void StartParty() {

        person1.Arrive(this);
        person2.Arrive(this);
    }

    public void AddDancers(PersonThatCanDance dancer) {
        dancers.Add(dancer);
    }

    private void StartMusic() {
        for (var dancer in dancers) {
            dancer.Dance();
        }
    }
}
```

A possibly more idiomatic alternative, is going by events.

```
public class PersonThatCanDance : IPerson {
    public void Arrive(Party party) {
        //Logic related to arriving
        ...
        party.OnCueMusic(this.Dance);
    }
    ...
}

public class Party {
    public delegate void Dance();
    ArrayList musicEvents = new ArrayList();

    ...

    public void OnCueMusic(Dance dance) {
        musicEvents.Add(dance);
    }

    private void StartMusic() {
        for (var musicEvent in musicEvents) {
            musicEvent();
        }
    }
}
```